# html canvas static objects disappear when another is dragged

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-draggable

I followed the tuturial on this [site](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) , which was recommenced, for creating draggable  objects. Here is the [code](http://simonsarris.com/project/canvasdemo/shapes.js)  by itself. My goal is to create a game with a draggable item (the item used to make a decision) and three non-draggable shapes (the choices).

I'm not sure how to make the three non-draggable objects. I tried making three squares with 
separate functions (i.e. fillSquare) so that they aren't draggable, but they disappear when I move the draggable item defeating the purpose of my game. I'm pretty sure I have to use some of the canvas states to keep the items on the screen but I keep getting confused about how to go about it. The code below is just shortened version of what is in the links posted above. Any help is appreciated.

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.w = w || 1;
    this.h = h || 1;
    this.fill = fill || '#AAAAAA';
}

// Draws this shape to a given context
Shape.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}

// Determine if a point is inside the shape's bounds
Shape.prototype.contains = function (mx, my) {
    // All we have to do is make sure the Mouse X,Y fall in the area between
    // the shape's X and (X + Height) and its Y and (Y + Height)
    return (this.x <= mx) && (this.x + this.w >= mx) && (this.y <= my) && (this.y + this.h >= my);
}

function CanvasState(canvas) {
    // **** First some setup! ****
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.width = canvas.width;
    this.height = canvas.height;
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // fixes mouse co-ordinate problems  when there's a border or padding. 
    var stylePaddingLeft, stylePaddingTop, styleBorderLeft, styleBorderTop;
    if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        this.stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10) || 0;
        this.stylePaddingTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10) || 0;
        this.styleBorderLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10) || 0;
        this.styleBorderTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10) || 0;
    }

    //helps protect mouse coordinates for pages with fixed-position bars
    var html = document.body.parentNode;
    this.htmlTop = html.offsetTop;
    this.htmlLeft = html.offsetLeft;

    // **** Keep track of state! ****
    this.valid = false; // when set to false, the canvas will redraw everything
    this.shapes = []; // the collection of things to be drawn
    this.dragging = false; // Keep track of when we are dragging

    // the current selected object. In the future we could turn this into an array for multiple selection
    this.selection = null;
    this.dragoffx = 0; // See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation
    this.dragoffy = 0;

    // **** Then events! ****
    //saves a reference to CanvasState so we can use it in events
    var myState = this;

    // Up, down, and move are for dragging
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
        var mx = mouse.x;
        var my = mouse.y;
        var shapes = myState.shapes;
        var l = shapes.length;
        for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (shapes[i].contains(mx, my)) {
                var mySel = shapes[i];
                // Keep track of where in the object we clicked
                // so we can move it smoothly (see mousemove)
                myState.dragoffx = mx - mySel.x;
                myState.dragoffy = my - mySel.y;
                myState.dragging = true;
                myState.selection = mySel;
                myState.valid = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        // If there was an object selected, we deselect it
        if (myState.selection) {
            myState.selection = null;
            myState.valid = false; // Need to clear the old selection border
        }
    }, true);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (myState.dragging) {
            var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
            // We don't want to drag the object by its top-left corner, we want to drag it
            // from where we clicked. Thats why we saved the offset and use it here
            myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragoffx;
            myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragoffy;
            myState.valid = false; // Something's dragging so we must redraw
        }
    }, true);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        myState.dragging = false;
    }, true);

    // **** Options! ****
    this.selectionColor = '#CC0000';
    this.selectionWidth = 2;
    this.interval = 30;
    setInterval(function () {
        myState.draw();
    }, myState.interval);
}

CanvasState.prototype.addShape = function (shape) {
    this.shapes.push(shape);
    this.valid = false;
}

CanvasState.prototype.clear = function () {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
}

// While draw is called as often as the INTERVAL variable demands,
// It only ever does something if the canvas gets invalidated by our code
CanvasState.prototype.draw = function () {
    // if our state is invalid, redraw and validate!
    if (!this.valid) {
        var ctx = this.ctx;
        var shapes = this.shapes;
        this.clear();

        // draw all shapes
        var l = shapes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var shape = shapes[i];
            // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
            if (shape.x > this.width || shape.y > this.height || shape.x + shape.w < 0 || shape.y + shape.h < 0) continue;
            shapes[i].draw(ctx);
        }

        // draw selection
        if (this.selection != null) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.selectionColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = this.selectionWidth;
            var mySel = this.selection;
            ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x, mySel.y, mySel.w, mySel.h);
        }

        this.valid = true;
    }
}


// Creates an object with x and y defined, set to the mouse position relative to the state's canvas
CanvasState.prototype.getMouse = function (e) {
    var element = this.canvas,
        offsetX = 0,
        offsetY = 0,
        mx, my;

    // Compute the total offset
    if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    // Add padding and border style widths to offset
    // Also add the <html> offsets in case there's a position:fixed bar
    offsetX += this.stylePaddingLeft + this.styleBorderLeft + this.htmlLeft;
    offsetY += this.stylePaddingTop + this.styleBorderTop + this.htmlTop;

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY;

    // We return a simple javascript object (a hash) with x and y defined
    return {
        x: mx,
        y: my
    };
}

function init() {
    var s = new CanvasState(document.getElementById('canvas'));
    s.addShape(new Shape(40, 40, 50, 50)); // The default is gray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `addShape()` (see example in the `init()` function at the end of the code you quoted).

Why not `fillRect()`?  Because each time draw() is called, it calls `clear()`, and then draws the shapes that were added via `addShape()`.

In other words, the canvas is being **ERASED** before each frame is drawn... and then the shapes that were added via `addShape()` are **REDRAWN**.  Again, for emphasis: all this drawing happens **EVERY FRAME**.  Nothing from the previous frame remains!

I would suggest adding an `isDraggable` property to each shape, which you can test for (and exit early) in the mouse event handlers.  I would start by adding it as a parameter to the `addShape()` function, and then store it in a property of the created shape.